# Pattern discriminator does not match

Tags: f#

New to F# and would like to know why I am getting a compile time error when defining the binaryMathFn.

I will also take suggestions on changing the title of this question. It's not the most descriptive :)

```
type Stack = StackContents of float list

let push item (StackContents stack) =
    match stack with
    | [] -> StackContents [item]
    | _ ->  StackContents (item::stack)

let pop (StackContents stack) =
    match stack with
    | [] -> failwith "Stack is empty, nothing to pop!"
    | h::t -> (h, StackContents t)    

let binaryMathFn fn (StackContents stack) = // Expression type is expected to be of type Stack?

    let item1, stack' = pop stack
    let item2, stack'' = pop stack'

    let result = fn item1 item2

    push result stack''
```

Comment: the answers are very good already - so just my 50ct - add types even when F# don't need them - you will help see problems faster and improve readability

Comment: I assume you're working from [this post](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/stack-based-calculator/). 

Note that once the primitives (push,pop) are defined, all the following functions (like binaryMathFn) do NOT need to unpack the stack (or see "inside" it), nor do they need to explicitly specify the type.

You can almost think of it as OO in a way. 

You have an "object" (Stack), you have some operations that work on the object (push, pop) and then everything else is built from that.

Comment: I was wondering why that was. Thanks for reading my mind on that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the types, but before I explain what's wrong, here's one way to make the `binaryMathFn` function compile:

```
let binaryMathFn fn stack =

    let item1, stack' = pop stack
    let item2, stack'' = pop stack'

    let result = fn item1 item2

    push result stack''
```

Your definition of `Stack` is a Discriminated Union with a single union case called `StackContents`. When you declare a function argument as `(StackContents stack)`, you are using a shorthand notation that states:

The input is of the type `Stack`, but immediately match that input with the single `StackContents` union case, effectively unpacking the `float list` from the input, and assign that `float list` to the symbol `stack`.

If you, like I suggest above, change the argument declaration to simply `stack`, the F# compiler can automatically infer that `stack` is a `Stack` value, because the function uses the `pop` function, which has this function signature:

```
Stack -> float * Stack
```

which is read as *a function that takes a `Stack` as input, and returns a tuple of `float` and `Stack` as output.* Since `binaryMathFn` calls `pop` with `stack`, the compiler can infer `stack` must be a `Stack` value.

Comment: Indeed this is a major problem with new F#ers comming from C# - the syntax looks so much like a normal argument-definition in C# that they don't see the difference

Comment: You are absolutely right there. I am trying very hard to start from scratch with F# but I can't help using concepts I've been using for 6 years :)

Answer (score 3):

So the problem is:

```
let binaryMathFn fn (StackContents stack)
```

Should be

```
let binaryMathFn fn (stack)
```

What is happening is that your definition is extracting the data.  In general, using this sort of pattern matching that you have used in the function definition is unidiomatic.